# Custom Form for create and update the blogposts give Page Not Found error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-2.2

I've create a simple form to create and update the blogposts. After the creation of the update view happen something strange that I can't solve.

**views.py**

```
def createPost(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BlogPostForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.slug_post = slugify(new_post.title)
            new_post.save()
            return redirect('post_list')
    else:
        form = BlogPostForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        }
    template = 'blog/editing/create_post.html'
    return render(request, template, context)


def updatePost(request, slug_post=None):
    update_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug_post=slug_post)
    form = BlogPostForm(request.POST or None, instance=update_post)
    if form.is_valid():
        update_post = form.save(commit=False)
        update_post.slug_post = slugify(update_post.title)
        update_post.save()
        return redirect('post_list')

    context = {
        'form': form,
        }
    template = 'blog/editing/create_post.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("blog/", views.listPost, name='post_list'),
    path("blog/<str:slug_post>/", views.singlePost, name='single_post'),

    path("blog/create-post/", views.createPost, name='create_post'),
    path("blog/<str:slug_post>/update-post/", views.updatePost, name='update_post'),
    path("blog/<str:slug_post>/delete-post/", views.deletePost, name='delete_post'),
]
```

**post_list.html**

```
  <div class="row">
    {% for post in post_list %}

      {% if forloop.first %}<div class="card-deck">{% endif %}
        <div class="card mb-3 shadow" style="max-width: 540px;">
          <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="{{ post.header_image_link }}" class="card-img" alt="{{ post.title }}" style="height: 250px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title"><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h4>
                <p class="card-text">{{ post.description }}</p>
                <p class="card-text my-0 py-0"><small class="text-muted"><strong>Published: </strong>{{ post.publishing_date|date }}</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" or forloop.last %}</div>{% endif %}
      {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" and not forloop.last %}<div class="card-deck">{% endif %}

      {% empty %}

      <div class="row justify-content-md-center my-3 mx-1 py-2 shadow bg-danger rounded">
        <div class="col-md-auto">
          <h1 class="text-center px-2 py-2" id="text-shadow">Empty list!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

**create_post.html**

```
<form class="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">

          <div class="form-group mb-4">
            <div>{{ form.title }}</div>
            <label for="id_title">
              <span class="text-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ form.title.help_text }}">
                <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>
              </span>
              <small class="text-danger">{{ form.title.errors }}</small>
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group mb-4">
            <div>{{ form.description }}</div>
            <label for="id_description">
              <span class="text-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{ form.description.help_text }}">
                <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>
              </span>
              <small class="text-danger">{{ form.description.errors }}</small>
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group mb-4">
            <div>{{ form.contents }}</div>
            <label for="id_contents">
              <span class="text-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{ form.contents.help_text }}">
                <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>
              </span>
              <small class="text-danger">{{ form.contents.errors }}</small>
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group mb-4">
            <div>{{ form.header_image_link }}</div>
            <label for="id_highlighted">
              <span class="text-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ form.header_image_link.help_text }}">
                <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>
              </span>
              <small class="text-danger">{{ form.header_image_link.errors }}</small>
            </label>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">

          <div class="form-inline mb-4 py-0">
            <div class="input-group mx-1">
              <label for="id_highlighted">{{ form.highlighted.label }}</label>
              <div class="ml-1">{{ form.highlighted }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group mx-1">
              <label for="id_draft">{{ form.draft.label }}</label>
              <div class="ml-1">{{ form.draft }}</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group mb-4">
            <label for="publishing_date_field">
              {{ form.publishing_date.label }}
              <small class="text-danger">{{ form.publishing_date.errors }}</small>
            </label>
            <div class="input-group date" data-target-input="nearest">
              {{ form.publishing_date }}
              <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#publishing_date_field" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <script>
              $(function () {
                $("#publishing_date_field").datetimepicker({
                  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
                });
              });
            </script>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group mb-4">
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center py-4 border border-warning rounded">
              <h5 class="text-justify px-3">Clicca sul tasto che segue per vedere l'elenco delle immagini. Potrai copiare il link all'immagine che ti interessa ed usarlo per creare l'immagine di testata o migliorare i contenuti del post.</h5>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mx-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-xl">Image list</button>
            </div>


            <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-scrollable">
                <div class="modal-content">

                  <div class="modal-body">
                    {% for image in images_url_list %}

                      {% if forloop.first %}<div class="card-deck">{% endif %}
                        <div class="card mx-1 my-1" style="height: 100%; width: 300px;">
                          <img src="{{ image.file.url }}" class="card-img-top h-100" alt="{{ image.file.url }}" id="{{ image.id }}">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" type="button" onclick="CopyToClipboard('{{ image.id }}')">Copy URL</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" or forloop.last %}</div>{% endif %}
                      {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" and not forloop.last %}<div class="card-deck">{% endif %}

                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-auto">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Pubblica">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </form>
```

I have this error message if I try to create a new post with my form:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/create-post/ Raised by:
>     blog.views.singlePost

As I said this happen after the creation of `updatePost`. If I comment  the path of the single post `path("blog/<str:slug_post>/", views.singlePost, name='single_post'),` I can create a post whitout problems.

What I've wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `path("blog/<str:slug_post>/", views.singlePost, name='single_post')`  to the bottom of your list, below the update and delete paths.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("blog/", views.listPost, name='post_list'),
    path("blog/create-post/", views.createPost, name='create_post'),
    path("blog/<str:slug_post>/update-post/", views.updatePost, name='update_post'),
    path("blog/<str:slug_post>/delete-post/", views.deletePost, name='delete_post'),
path("blog/<str:slug_post>/", views.singlePost, name='single_post'),
]
```

Comment: It run, thank you. I don't understand why happen this, is the first time. Can you explane why? I've another two model similar to this, whit the same order of path that have this, and they work fine buth in creation that in the others instances.